# Virtual background in agora web sdk

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I am using [agora-meeting-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agora-meeting-core) for a meeting web app. Now, I need to add a virtual background. How can I implement it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like virtual backgrounds isn't a feature of this open source Agora example project, or the Web SDK actually.

It is a feature of the Native SDK though, (iOS, macOS, Android, Windows)

Comment: It possible to use C++ SDK through plugin in web? Or process stream through third party package before its boardcasted?